# How to see full ant build error that is cut off

Tags: java, ant

I am currently working on a java project with existing sources. An existing `build.xml` for ant is there, but compiling and generating wsdl file is failing.

Anyhow using `ant -v` the output is still cut off leaving me with not enough information to find the problem.

Output where the error occurs:

```
    GenerateServer-Config.wsdd:
         [echo] generate server-config.wsdd for webservice
         [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
         [java]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
         [java]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
         [java]     at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:177)
         [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
         [java]     at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
         [java]     at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)
         [java]     at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDTypeMapping.getLanguageSpecificType(WSDDTypeMapping.java:183)
         [java]     at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.deployTypeMapping(WSDDService.java:542)
         [java]     at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.initTMR(WSDDService.java:253)
         [java]     at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.<init>(WSDDService.java:233)
         [java]     at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.<init>(WSDDDeployment.java:192)
         [java]     at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.setDocument(WSDDDocument.java:139)
         [java]     at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.<init>(WSDDDocument.java:65)
         [java]     at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.configureEngine(FileProvider.java:179)
         [java]     at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.init(AxisEngine.java:172)
         [java]     at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.<init>(AxisEngine.java:156)
         [java]     at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.<init>(AxisServer.java:88)
         [java]     at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.<init>(AxisServer.java:83)
         [java]     at org.apache.axis.utils.Admin.main(Admin.java:289)
         [java] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
         [java]     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
         [java]     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:142)
         [java]     at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:272)
         [java]     at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.<init>(FileAppender.java:96)
         [java]     at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.<init>(FileAppender.java:107)
         [java]     at de.atip.Log.createAppender(Log.java:103)
         [java]     at de.atip.Log.<init>(Log.java:78)
         [java]     at de.atip.voxguard.UserInfo.<clinit>(UserInfo.java:33)
         [java]     ... 19 more

BUILD FAILED
```

So I can see there are 19 more error messages - but even with verbose mode ant does not tell me them. Is there any way to output those errors?

Comment: Check if you have defined file for FileAppender. It looks like there is not name defined for FileOutputStream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Javadoc for `Throwable.printStacktrace`:

> Note the presence of lines containing the characters "...". These lines
>   indicate that the remainder of the stack trace for this exception
>   matches the indicated number of frames from the bottom of the stack
>   trace of the exception that was caused by this exception (the
>   "enclosing" exception). This shorthand can greatly reduce the length
>   of the output in the common case where a wrapped exception is thrown
>   from same method as the "causative exception" is caught.

In other words the rest of the stack trace for your `NullPointerException` is the same as the trace for `ExceptionInInitializerError`.

Comment: because I wanted to know this - this is the answer for this question :) I did not want to ask how to solve - though any hints are welcome. Thank your for this information.